# filter out the contacts having no phone numbers

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am trying to fetch the contact numbers from a phone here is my query, but the issue is I am getting few contact names which doesn't have a phone number at all. Can any one tell me 
how can I filter out that contacts who don't have contact numbers?

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
String[] projection = new String[] {
    ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,       
    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID

    };
String selection = 
    ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '" +1+"'";

String sortOrder =  ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME+ " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '" +1+"' AND "
                   ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = '" +1+"'";
```

Comment: tried using HAS_PHONE_NUMBER but result is same it is still displaying contacts with no phone numbers

Answer (score 1):

Add [ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html#HAS_PHONE_NUMBER) to your selection String.

Thus your code becomes:

```
String selection = 
    ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '" +1+"'"
    + " AND " + ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = '" +1+"'";
```

Comment: i tried using `HAS_PHONE_NUMBER` but result is same it is still displaying contacts with no phone numbers